# Understanding dynamic linker

Tags: linker, elf

I am wondering why dynamic linker have to search which function in which library.

Can this information be put into elf file by the compile time linker?

If this is done, dynamic linker can find a function directly  instead searching.

Comment: Well that wouldn't be **dynamic** anymore, would it?

Comment: No. Just linker will know which function in which shared library. Linking still be done run time.

Comment: That's literally what dynamic linking does.

Comment: If I say about ld.so;
Maps a shared library to excutable address space.If lazy binding is active, when a function is called, linker finds where that function  and update the global offset table

Comment: You can't just call lazy loading "dynamic linking" and expect anyone to understand what you're talking about. Anyway, the main purpose is to speed up the startup time and reduce memory consumption. Of course calling the function is a bit slower as a tradeoff.

Comment: I didn't say lazy binding and dynamic linking same things. I know that purpose of lazy binding is reduce startup time. I just said that "If lazy binding is active".So If the program is compiled without -fno-plt option

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering why dynamic linker have to search which function in which library.

As opposed to recording at static link time which shared library the symbol was defined in, and searching *only* that library, similar to what happens on Windows?

There are a few reasons:

1. Originally, shared libraries were designed to emulate archive libraries, and it was common to have several archive libraries define the same symbol.
2. It turns out that *not* recording the library name allows for symbol interpositioning at runtime, especially with `LD_PRELOAD`.
3. In the usual case of a few shared libraries, searching the additional libraries doesn't cost that much (searching is done via hash table, not linearly).

For (1), you could still record the *first* library the symbol was defined in.

For (3), it [turns out](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16709) that some build systems violate the usual case (with 10,000 shared libraries), and the overhead of searching them all becomes significant. There are ways to avoid that overhead without invalidating the usual symbol lookup rules though.